# How to structure a project with multiple files and internal dependencies to be uploaded to PyPI

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, pypi

I have created a project that has the following structure:

```
TFNeuralNetworks/
    .git/
    .gitignore
    LICENSE
    README.md
    setup.py
    TFNeuralNetworks/
        __init__.py
        MLP.py
        NeuralNetwork.py
        RNN.py
```

`TFNeuralNetworks/setup.py` contains all the relevant parameters to a call to `setuptools.setup()`.

`TFNeuralNetworks/TFNeuralNetworks/__init__.py` contains just the following:

```
import NeuralNetwork
import MLP
import RNN
```

Each of these 3 files contain a single class with the same name as the file (i.e. to use this class, `from MLP import MLP` would be needed). Is this the correct content needed for this `__init__.py` file?

If I run this file from the directory that I am creating the project in, it runs fine. However, when I upload the project to PyPI (or even do `pip install .` to pip istall it locally), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/TFNeuralNetworks/TFNeuralNetworks/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import NeuralNetwork
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NeuralNetwork'
```

I have followed this structure from several online tutorials and can't see where I am going wrong - what is the issue here?

EDIT:

I still cannot get my head around this. All I want to be able to do is create a package [from this code base](https://github.com/KevOBrien/TFNeuralNetworks) that I can pip install, and then do something along the lines of:

```
from TFNeuralNetworks import RNN

rnn = RNN(num_inputs=2, num_outputs=1, hidden_sizes=[100])
```

while still also allowing me to run the code locally for testing.

Comment: `from . import NeuralNetwork`

Comment: Ok, that got a bit further before a similar error occured. Both the `MLP` and `RNN` classes are subclasses of `NeuralNetwork`, so both have `from NeuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork`. This now throws an error, how should this be fixed?

Comment: `from TFNeuralNetworks import NeuralNetworks` or the same as above.

Comment: This is confusing me so much I am getting further errors now. I don't understand this required structure at all. Is there no way that the code and these imports can be written in such a way that files can be run locally from within the directory, and also to be uploaded to PyPI and then pip installed?

Comment: @PeterWood Could I ask you to look at the code here: https://github.com/KevOBrien/TFNeuralNetworks and recommend how it should be structred and the imports done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From looking into your repository, you should use your imports as following

```
MLP.py
  from . import NeuralNetwork
RNN.py
  from . import NeuralNetwork
__init__.py
  (LEAVE BLANK)
```

As far as I can remember in py3 you can then use modules internally like

```
NeuralNetwork.NeuralNetwork

# or if you prefer
from . import NeuralNetwork.NeuralNetwork as NeuralNetwork
```

That way you will be able to instal with pip.
Next, you can use it like so

```
from neuralnetwork import RNN

RNN.do_some_code()
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, except now when I call `from TFNeuralNetworks import RNN` I get an error with: `RNN.py", line 48, in <module> class RNN(NeuralNetwork): TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`. I don't understand which `__init__()` method this is referring to.

Comment: Also, is there no way to structure these dependencies and imports such that I can run my code locally from its directory, as well as uploading it to PyPI?

Comment: My idea would be to have a `try: from . import NeuralNetwork except Exception as e: import NeuralNetwork`